# c++, how to Get the solution directory in the code

Tags: c++, visual-c++, macros, preprocessor

I am writing unit test for a dll function that returns its full path.
the test project and dll project are both in same solution.

I was thinking of get the solution directory and append rest of path to assert.

in the preprocessor definitions of the test project defined : `_SOLUTIONDIR=$(SolutionDir);`

but in the test file I get `#define _SOLUTIONDIR C:\*\Project\ 
                      expands to C:\*\Project\ 
                      unrecognized token`

How should I cast or convert it to string? or in general what is the best way to get relative paths?

```
dll file has function returning 
--------------------------------
 EXTERN_C IMAGE_DOS_HEADER __ImageBase;
LPTSTR  strDLLPath1 = new TCHAR[_MAX_PATH];
        ::GetModuleFileName((HINSTANCE)&__ImageBase, strDLLPath1, _MAX_PATH);
        wstring temp1(strDLLPath1);
        string temp2(temp1.begin(), temp1.end());
return temp2;
```

Comment: I tried whether this could be solved with [macro stringize operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace#.23_and_.23.23_operators) but it doesn't work. [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d7dec4c1dd203ad4) So, the only chance could be to enclose `$(SolutionDir)` into quotes. You may test whether this works (with proper replacement). Otherwise, I see no chance.

Comment: Although, it would if \\ were used instead of \: [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/648ed05514ecf969). (This is what I hadn't expected.) However, probably still no solution for your problem... (And it means that even if delimiting with quotes would work it doesn't form a valid C string.)

Comment: @Scheff Thanks for reply, so I tried `_SOLUTIONDIR="$(SolutionDir);"`. it returns `#define _SOLUTIONDIR "C:\*\Project\\" expands to "C:\*\Project\\" `  but what is in between double quotes are not having any type class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to define `_SOLUTIONDIR` as follow

```
_SOLUTIONDIR=R"($(SolutionDir))"
```

Comment: Nice use of a raw string literal, but beware of paths ending with `)`!